# How to get latest Shopify api_version with API call

Tags: python, shopify-api

How to get latest Shopify `api_version` with API call in Python?

This Python code does not work:

```
import requests
import json

shop = 'your_shop'
access_token = 'your_access_token'

headers = {
    'X-Shopify-Access-Token': access_token,
}

response = requests.get(f'https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/versions.json', headers=headers)
versions = json.loads(response.text)

latest_stable_version = next((version for version in versions if version['status'] == 'stable'), None)

if latest_stable_version:
    print(f"The latest stable version is {latest_stable_version['handle']}")
else:
    print("No stable version found.")
```

But Response is 404 with '{"errors":"Not Found"}':

request:

```
<PreparedRequest [GET]>
status_code:
404
text:
'{"errors":"Not Found"}'
```